# Call a Service from an Activity

Tags: android, service

I am calling (trying) a Service from an activity.  I had already built such a call for another Service already in the App successfully.  That one works fine, but this one does not.  FOr the life of me, I can not figure out why.

I put some Log.d flags in the code to tell me what is going on.  Basically when I am in RecordActivity I click a button.  In LogCat I see the OnCreate, InitRecorder and the OnDestroy . But the onStartCommand is missing.  To me that means that onStartCommend never gets executed.  Perhaps you can see why?

Here is the Service code:

```
public class SnoreSensor extends Service {

    public static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 16000;
    private AudioRecord mRecorder;
    private File mRecording;
    private short[] mBuffer;
    // private final String startRecordingLabel = "Start recording";
    // private final String stopRecordingLabel = "Stop recording";
    private boolean mIsRecording = false;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private static String TAG = "SnoreSensor";
    int amplitudeFinal;

    /**
     * //REMOVED TO CHANGE FROM ACTIVITY TO SERVICE
     * 
     * @Override public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     *           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     *           setContentView(R.layout.view_snoresensor);
     * 
     *           initRecorder();
     * 
     *           mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
     * 
     *           final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
     *           button.setText(startRecordingLabel);
     * 
     *           button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     * @Override public void onClick(final View v) { if (!mIsRecording) {
     *           button.setText(stopRecordingLabel); mIsRecording = true;
     *           mRecorder.startRecording(); mRecording = getFile("raw");
     *           startBufferedWrite(mRecording); } else {
     *           button.setText(startRecordingLabel); mIsRecording = false;
     *           mRecorder.stop(); File waveFile = getFile("wav"); try {
     *           rawToWave(mRecording, waveFile); } catch (IOException e) {
     *           Toast.makeText(SnoreSensor.this, e.getMessage(),
     *           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } Toast.makeText(SnoreSensor.this,
     *           "Recorded to " + waveFile.getName(),
     *           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } } }); }
     **/

    public void onCreate() {

        Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate");
        mIsRecording = false;
        initRecorder();
    }

    public void onStartCommand() {

        Log.d(TAG, "OnStartCommand");
        mIsRecording = true;
        mRecorder.startRecording();
        mRecording = getFile("raw");
        startBufferedWrite(mRecording);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.d(TAG, "OnDestroy");
        mIsRecording = false;
        mRecorder.stop();
        File waveFile = getFile("wav");
        try {
            rawToWave(mRecording, waveFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(SnoreSensor.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        Toast.makeText(SnoreSensor.this, "Recorded to " + waveFile.getName(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mRecorder.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void initRecorder() {
        Log.d(TAG, "initRecorder");
        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        mBuffer = new short[bufferSize];
        mRecorder = new AudioRecord(
                MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION, SAMPLE_RATE,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                bufferSize);
    }

    private void startBufferedWrite(final File file) {

        Log.d(TAG, "startBufferedWrite");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DataOutputStream output = null;
                try {
                    output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                            new FileOutputStream(file)));
                    while (mIsRecording) {
                        double sum = 0;
                        int readSize = mRecorder.read(mBuffer, 0,
                                mBuffer.length);
                        for (int i = 0; i < readSize; i++) {
                            output.writeShort(mBuffer[i]);
                            sum += mBuffer[i] * mBuffer[i];
                        }
                        if (readSize > 0) {
                            final double amplitude = sum / readSize;
                            final int amplitudeFinal = (int) Math
                                    .sqrt(amplitude);
                            mProgressBar.setProgress(amplitudeFinal);
                            Log.d(TAG, "amplitude: " + amplitudeFinal);

                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(SnoreSensor.this, e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } finally {
                    mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                    if (output != null) {
                        try {
                            output.flush();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(SnoreSensor.this, e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                output.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(SnoreSensor.this,
                                        e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void rawToWave(final File rawFile, final File waveFile)
            throws IOException {

        byte[] rawData = new byte[(int) rawFile.length()];
        DataInputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(rawFile));
            input.read(rawData);
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                input.close();
            }
        }

        DataOutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(waveFile));
            // WAVE header
            // see http://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/
            writeString(output, "RIFF"); // chunk id
            writeInt(output, 36 + rawData.length); // chunk size
            writeString(output, "WAVE"); // format
            writeString(output, "fmt "); // subchunk 1 id
            writeInt(output, 16); // subchunk 1 size
            writeShort(output, (short) 1); // audio format (1 = PCM)
            writeShort(output, (short) 1); // number of channels
            writeInt(output, SAMPLE_RATE); // sample rate
            writeInt(output, SAMPLE_RATE * 2); // byte rate
            writeShort(output, (short) 2); // block align
            writeShort(output, (short) 16); // bits per sample
            writeString(output, "data"); // subchunk 2 id
            writeInt(output, rawData.length); // subchunk 2 size
            // Audio data (conversion big endian -> little endian)
            short[] shorts = new short[rawData.length / 2];
            ByteBuffer.wrap(rawData).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
                    .asShortBuffer().get(shorts);
            ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(shorts.length * 2);
            for (short s : shorts) {
                bytes.putShort(s);
            }
            output.write(bytes.array());
        } finally {
            if (output != null) {
                output.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private File getFile(final String suffix) {
        Time time = new Time();
        time.setToNow();
        return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                time.format("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") + "." + suffix);
    }

    private void writeInt(final DataOutputStream output, final int value)
            throws IOException {
        output.write(value >> 0);
        output.write(value >> 8);
        output.write(value >> 16);
        output.write(value >> 24);
    }

    private void writeShort(final DataOutputStream output, final short value)
            throws IOException {
        output.write(value >> 0);
        output.write(value >> 8);
    }

    private void writeString(final DataOutputStream output, final String value)
            throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
            output.write(value.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    /*********************************************
     * BROADCAST THE UPDATE TO ACTIVITYRECORDSLEEP
     *********************************************/
    private void sendSnoreUpdate() {

        Log.d(TAG, "sender Broadcasting Amplitude " + amplitudeFinal);
        Intent intent = new Intent("SnoreUpdate");
        intent.putExtra("Amplitude", amplitudeFinal);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

}// End
```

In my Activity start() I have the following to call the Service:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                mSnoreReceiver, new IntentFilter("SnoreUpdate"));
.....
.....

    //Intent startSnoreSensorService = new Intent(this, SnoreSensor.class);
            //startService(startSnoreSensorService);
            startService(new Intent(this, SnoreSensor.class));
```

I was simply testing to see if there is a difference but both types work fine.  In the Manifest I have this:

```
<service
            android:name=".sensors.SnoreSensor"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>
```

Comment: you not overriding the (correct) onStart method.

Comment: this is exactly why you should always use the @Override annotation where overriding something

Comment: to be honest I did not know I was overriding anything.  Still a new meat here.  I am only 10, gimme a break  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you take a look at `Service` class, you will see there method `onStartCommand(Intent i, int flags, int startId)`, which you have to override to communicate with service in such way. But you created method which signature doesn't match one, that declared in `Service` class. Thats why this method haven't been called when you start your service.

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnStartCommand");
        mIsRecording = true;
        mRecorder.startRecording();
        mRecording = getFile("raw");
        startBufferedWrite(mRecording);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Comment: topic starter created another method onStartCommand without parameters. See code above. That's why it has not been called ever.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but can you explain why this works please?

Comment: Rather than simply putting in a chunk of code, an answer with an explanation is much higher quality. For example, in addition to this block of code it would be very useful to point out two important things: the method signature is modified from what the original post contains (which is quite significant in Java), and that the method is now returning a hint to the OS to leave the service around even after current users have disconnected from it (if necessary, such as when a service will be frequently connected/disconnected).

Comment: @Cybergei the method you provided does not match the signature used by Android -- making your method essentially invisible to the system and meaning the system calls the default (doesn't do much) onStartCommand method instead. Once you fix the signature, it will properly override the default method allowing it to be called properly.

Comment: i don't understand, you said that "I had already built such a call for another Service already in the App successfully". Therefore I thought it was just a little mistake and you will understand why onStartCommand haven't been called

Comment: I have built another service, but the recommendation that you have sent does not match my other service.  I do thank you for it as it did work.  I simply did not understand why.  Not the other service is just a tap into the light sensor so perhaps that is why it is different.

Comment: as long as it properly dies when I touch the stop button, that is what matters